# segmentation fault on simple loop

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the number of elements of given matrix,for example M[2][3] = [1,2,3][3,4,5]
should give the number of elements from 0 trough 9 in a nxm array.
The algorithm is correct up until line 34(M[i][j] = i + 2;) in which I'm having a segmentation fault.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COL 10
#define MAX 10
void Print_Matrix(int **M,int row,int col);
int MallocX(int **M,int row,int col);
int main(void)
{
    int **M = 0x0;
    int count[MAX] = {0};
    int i,j;
    
    
    
    if(MallocX(M,ROW,COL)){
        fprintf(stdout,"Could not allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0;i<ROW;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<COL;j++){
            M[i][j] = i + 2;
        }
    }
    Print_Matrix(M,ROW,COL);
    for(i = 0;i<ROW;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<COL;j++){
            ++count[M[i][j]];
        }
    }
    
    for(j = 0;j<MAX;j++){
        if(count[j]){
            printf("%d %d\n",j,count[j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i<ROW;i++){
        free(M[i]);
    }
    free(M);
}
int MallocX(int **M,int row,int col)
{
    int i;
    M = (int **) malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    if(M == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory\n");
        free(M);
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0;i<row;i++){   
        M[i] = (int *) malloc(col * sizeof(int));
        if(M[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory\n");
            free(M[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void Print_Matrix(int **M,int row,int col)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<row;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%d ",M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're writing past the end of `count`.  The maximum valid index into `count` is `MAX-1`, i.e. 9.  The largest value in `M` is 9+2 = 11.  So you're writing two elements past the end with `++count[M[i][j]]`.

Comment: but It gives segfault on (M[i][j] = i + 2)

Comment: ok. I will try it.

Comment: still gives me seg fault.

Comment: Actually, `MallocX` is a problem as well.  That's probably the cause of the first seg fault.  It's allocating memory, storing it in a local variable, then returning without any effect.  You need to *return* the allocated memory (either with a `return` statement, or storing to a pointer).  As it is, `M` is undefined when in `main` when you try to write to it.

Comment: but isn't M** passed by reference?

Comment: All arguments in C are passed by value.  You can simulate pass-by-reference by explicitly passing the address of a variable, but you aren't doing that.  So, that's your main bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are passing `M` by value, not reference. Your `MallocX` allocates memory for your matrix, but those allocations are orphaned when you return to the main program, where `M` is still `0x0` (or `NULL`), which is why allocation functions typically return a pointer. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
int **MallocX(int row,int col)
{
    int **Matrix, i;

    Matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    if(Matrix == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        Matrix[i] = (int*) malloc(col * sizeof(int));
        if(Matrix[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory (%d)\n",i);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                free(Matrix[j]);
            free(Matrix);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return Matrix;
}
```

Then in `main`, call it with:

```
if (!(M = MallocX(ROW,COL)) {
    fprintf(stdout,"Could not allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Note that in your original code, you were calling `free(M)` when `M` was `NULL`, which will itself cause a segfault. So I've tidied up your garbage collection a bit too.

Comment: Calling `free` with a `NULL` pointer is allowed by the C standard. So OP's `free` calls were useless, but also harmless.

Comment: I was not aware of that, @user3386109. Learn something new every day!